# Fórmulas do Excel continuam funcionando após serem importadas para um DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-excel, mysql

Eu tenho uma planilha no Excel onde eu importo ela, para apresentar os dados em um `DataGridView`, eu gostaria de saber se as fórmulas que estão contidas na planilha ainda continuam a funcionar no `DataGridView`.

Para ser mais especifico a fórmula que eu gostaria que continuasse funcionando, ou fosse implementada de alguma outra maneira, é basicamente uma subtração de datas, onde eu devo subtrair a data de hoje com a data da vigência(que é uma data fixa) e mostrar a quantidade de meses entre essas datas em uma nova célula.

Estou importando a planilha para o banco de forma manual, pelo [mysql-workbench](/questions/tagged/mysql-workbench), e recupero essas informações para o `DataGrid` através de um `SELECT`.

***Importação pelo workbench***

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  
'importexcel/testeimport_utf.csv'
INTO TABLE MINHA TABELA character set utf8 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(CAMPOS DA TABELA);
```

Acredito que não há como implementar uma fórmula Excel atráves do MySQL, mas gostaria de saber se eu conseguiria inserir essa fórmula no `DataGrid` de alguma outra maneira, porque senão os meses irão se passar, e a coluna que mostra quantidade de meses irá permanecer estática.

Comment: Um banco de dados não é uma planilha. O SGBD não tem um tipo de dado que seja uma fórmula. Todos os dados de cada coluna pertencem a um único domínio. É possível aplicar funções aos dados selecionados de seu banco de dados, você terá que pesquisar dentre as funções existentes quais as que se adequam a suas necessidades.

Comment: Entendi, irei pesquisar sobre funções que possam realizar essa operação. Sinceramente gostaria de fazer isso através do C# mesmo mas não faço ideia de como manipular dados estáticos em uma Grid.

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível que o MySQL "interprete" as formulas feitas no excel, a solução é:
Crie uma VIEW no MySQL, realizando o calculo com as datas :

```
timestampdiff(MONTH,SuaColuna,now()) AS TEMPO_DECORRIDO_MINUTOS
```

Comment: O `timestampdiff()` realmente consegue fazer esse trabalho, vou ver se consigo encaixar ele da melhor maneira possível no meu problema, ótima sugestão. Mas no caso ai você colocou `MINUTE` mas eu quero os Meses então no caso seria `MONTH` na resposta.

Comment: Sim, coloquei em minutos como exemplo, mas  dependendo da situação fica mais fácil de se trabalhar em minutos.